# Join results of two queries in SQL and produce a result given some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've never used SQL until now, so please bear with me. I have a table of departments:

[image]

I have written two queries as follows:

```
-- nbr of staff associated with each dept. 
SELECT count(departmentId) as freq
FROM staff
GROUP BY departmentId

-- nbr of students associated with each dept. 
SELECT count(departmentId) as freq
FROM StudentAssignment
GROUP BY departmentId
```

These produce the following two tables:

[image][image]

For each department id 1 to 5, I need to divide the `studentFreq` by the `staffFreq` and show the department id and description if the result is greater than 2.

If the `staffFreq` i.e. number of staff, for a department id is zero then I need to show that department id and description too.

So for example, in this case I want to produce a table with the department ids of 1, 4 and 5 and their corresponding descriptions: Computing, Classics and Mechanical Engineering.

Computing because 7 / 2 > 2. Classics and ME because 0 staff are assigned to those depts.

Comment: YOu say that query results in below dataset, however, that Query isn't valid T-SQL. It doesn't look like any type of SQL, to be honest. A `JOIN` belongs in the `FROM`, not between 2 `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Sorry you're right. That JOIN statement shouldn't have been there and I've removed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a `left join`, starting with the `departments` table:

```
SELECT d.*,
       s.freq as as num_staff, sa.freq as num_students,
       sa.freq * 1.0 / s.freq as student_staff_ratio
FROM deptartments d LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT departmentId, count(*) as freq
      FROM staff
      GROUP BY departmentId
     ) s
     ON s.departmentId = d.department_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT departmentId, count(*) as freq
      FROM StudentAssignment
      GROUP BY departmentId
     ) sa
     ON sa.departmentId = d.departmentId;
```

Notes:

- This should missing values as `NULL` rather than `0`.  You can assign `0` instead using `COALESCE()`:  `COALESCE(s.freq, 0) as num_staff`.
- SQL Server does integer division, so 7 / 2 = 3, not 3.5.  I think you would typically want the fractional component.